# How solve Incompatible types error (E2010) with class casting in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, class, types, casting

I have a code like this:

```
TBase = class

end;

TClassA = class(TBase)

end;

TClassB = class(TBase)

end;
```

Now I need of a procedure with a parameter, this procedure must be accept TBase object and all TBase children (TClassA and TClassB), I have try this:

```
procedure MyProcedure(item: TBase);
```

but if I try to pass a TClassA or TClassB I get an error: "E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBase' and 'class of TClassA'".

I don't have understand my error.
Thanks

Note: before post I have try to find a similar question without success, if you know it please link me the anwser.

Comment: "class of TClassA" tells me you have some more code that we cannot see. Can you show your code where you're actually calling this?

Comment: There's no "class casting" (or any other "casting" happening) in the code you posted. If you have a problem calling `MyProcedure`, you should **post the code** that calls `MyProcedure`.

Comment: It would have been trivial for you to show a complete program the illustrated the error. We could have given you a definitive answer immediately. Instead you omitted the most important line of code. Why? Why make it hard for us? Show a complete program, 15 lines long, that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: You still haven't edited this question to include the most critical line of code which we need to see to be able to help you. Now I have no choice but to cast my down-vote.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can see you getting that error is if you are calling `MyProcedure()` like this:

```
MyProcedure(TClassA);
```

When you should be calling it like this instead:

```
var
  ca: TClassA;
...
MyProcedure(ca);
```

In other words, it is expecting a pointer to an object instance, but you are passing it a class type instead.

Comment: In Delphi 2009, the error message I get is `E2010 Incompatible types: 'TBase' and 'Class reference'`. Maybe it has changed in Delphi 2010.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the text of the error says. The cause is the same - the procedure is expecting an object pointer as input, but the calling code is not passing in an object pointer.

Comment: I call MyProcedure with object as you tell: ca: TClassA; MyProcedure(ca); but I get the error. Use Delphi XE3.

Comment: @Martin No, you do not. Why can't you put your entire program in the question? It can be cut down to <15 lines.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Given your class declarations and your procedure, you can do

```
var
  b: TBase;
  ca: TClassA;
  cb: TClassB;
begin
  MyProcedure(b);
  MyProcedure(ca);
  MyProcedure(cb);
```

and it will compile just fine. Apparently, what you *do* pass to `MyProcedure` *isn't in fact*  a `TBase`, `TClassA`, or a `TClassB`.

Comment: Instead it's a `class of TClassA`